# Release an object without a pointer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I’ve just started developing for iPhone and am trying to get my head around memory management.  I made a small program that shows a map and an annotation on the map. For the annotation I made a simple class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol.

To create and add the annotation I wrote this:

```
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:[[MyAnnotation alloc] init]];
```

It worked fine until I tried to release the object. Nothing to release. This is what I would have done in C#, I guess it doesn’t work without garbage collection?

So is this the only way to do it?

```
MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

[self.myMapView addAnnotation: myAnnotation];

[myAnnotation release];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:[[[MyAnnotation alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

Comment: Sorry I am late. I am still struggling with this, and your answer is the one I am going for. I've managed to post this question one more time, this time focusing on memory leaks, got the same answer as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the accepted way to handle a situation like this. You could have also called `autorelease` as in codelark's answer, but on the limited memory environment of the iPhone, autoreleasing can sometimes cause problems due to objects lingering for a while before they are finally released. It's a good practice to avoid autorelease where possible.

Comment: "It's a good practice to avoid autorelease where possible" -- I don't agree. It's only to be avoided when you're allocating hundreds or thousands of objects at once. In this case it's the correct idiom.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer (that example #2 is how it's commonly done), but avoiding autorelease without a reason is just cargo-cult programming. In this case, the object is already being retained by an object that will stay in memory past the current event loop, so avoiding autorelease will save absolutely *no* memory.

Comment: The criticism is noted and appreciated. I'll remember to better qualify my statements on the issue in the future.

Comment: Avoiding autorelease is absolutely not common nor advised, NSAutoreleasePool are allocated and released regularly and are pretty fast at sending release to their objects... Do not avoid autorelease if you don't know why, autorelease and release have their own uses, know them and use them properly, you should not have any problem... Also remember to learn the memory management rules !

Answer (score 0):

Everybody, thanks for the answers.

It seems to me that this code is the one that most resembles the solution I was thinking of in the first place.

```
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:[[[MyAnnotation alloc] init] autorelease]];
```